# Gurobi & Python:How to create a constraint which includes a variable and a kind of index(two indices simultaneous)

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, constraints, gurobi

I would like to write the constraint code as the content of picture.
[image]

```
#index:
J=['j1','j2','j3','j4','j5','j6','j7','j8','j9','j10','j11','j12','j13','j14','j15','j16','j17','j18','j19','j20', 'j21']

#variable of decision
F= m.addVars(J , vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="Fj")
```

I have tried to create a letter to instead "J+1" but obviously the code shouldn't have two kinds of index.

Comment: Start with a 2-dimensional array `J=[['j',1],['j',2]]...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a short way, but it works.

```
for j_index, j_value in enumerate(J[:-1]):
    m.addConstr(F[J[j_index+1]]<=F[j_value])
```

Note: [Gurobi examples page can be useful](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/python_examples.html).

Comment: Dear kur ag:
Thank you for answering.
I also had asked this problem on GUROBI forum website. I would like to share other answer to you to exchange.

you could use integers as indices, i.e.,

#index

J=[int(i)+1 for i in range(21)]
#code

b=len(J)-1
c=0
for j in J:
    c+=1
    if c<=b:
        m.addConstr((F[j+1]<=F[j]) ,'c'+str(j)
Please note that you have to use addConstr instead of addConstrs.
From: Jaromił Najman

Comment: It seems that y answer is shorter. If you accept my answer, don't forget check it.